# Is there a secret Jon Skeet Hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Since there's plenty of secret hats, is there a [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) hat?

- Jon Skeet is amazing
- Jon Skeet coded his last project entirely in Microsoft Paint, just for the challenge.
- Jon Skeet is immutable. If something's going to change, it's going to have to be the rest of the universe.

Comment: Only Jon Skeet can see and use the hat...

Comment: What if we praise him and grant him our souls?

Comment: This could see use for a Jon Skeet fan club (like [Rainbow Dash fan club](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjLdtCPDzAg) in a certain cartoon).

Comment: I have the Jon Skeet hat. It is only for very special people, mortals need not apply. It is not only secret, but also invisible. Also the team has vowed to keep quiet about it even when asked.

Comment: Still awaiting Jon Skeet to answer...

Comment: If a user wants to wear a custom hat that only they can wear, they would just edit their profile picture.

Comment: Why is this so downvoted?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Extremely unlikely.

Because only Jon Skeet is worthy of wearing that hat.

And he doesn't need to because he's already Jon Skeet.

Comment: In which case, it is no longer a Jon Skeet Hat, but a hat Jon Skeet is wearing.

Comment: It could be if you receive an up vote from Jon Skeet. A "Skeet Approved" stamp. :p