# How many hats are there in total?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016

It's Christmas and a lot of people are seeking Stack Exchange Hats.

There are some [obvious hats](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), but there are a lot of hidden hats.

Is the total number of hats known to the public?

Comment: 'Why is [How to handle programming questions with many, many errors?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321280/how-to-handle-programming-questions-with-many-many-errors?rq=1) a "Related" question? Oh, wait, I think I see.

Comment: I wonder if there's a [Jon Skeet hat this year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312360/is-there-a-secret-jon-skeet-hat)

Comment: I have got 4 secret hats till now ... How many of them have been introduced?

Comment: @rahul The community is tracking the ones we know about [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/153008)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The total numbers of hats is a secret until after Winter Bash is over.  At that point, we'll write up a end of hats post and give more details and stats on how many times each hat was won.

Comment: There are 28 regular hats and as of today 11 secret hats have been given, so the current count is 39, which is the current score of this answer at the time I am writing this comment :)

Comment: @Eran Not anymore!

Answer (score 17):

Some hats are secret. People are collecting a list of [all known hats here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) but it's possible that more secret hats will turn up.

Answer (score 0):

One way to explore what hats might be available that you haven't seen yet is to check the [leaderboard](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com).

Of course, it isn't exhaustive, as mentioned previously, but it is kind of fun to see what others have earned, and depending on the hat criteria, hanging around these users can sometimes itself be the trigger for the hat.